# Roslyn code refactoring - how to communicate failure reason to user?

Tags: .net, dialog, refactoring, roslyn

I'm creating a Roslyn extension to automate routine refactoring. When developer right-clicks on a type, Roslyn should offer to regenerate its constructor with some default code present. However, this operation may sometimes fail due to type structure, for example, when there is more than 1 constructor.

I'd like to inform developer about the reason for failure and advice on what to do.

I don't want to disable the refactoring in such case, since that would offer no information on why it is not available, and how to bring it back. So, I'm left with an option to show a dummy refactoring that does nothing, but contains needed message in its name i.e. "Regenerate constructor not available, because type has more than one constructor".

Is there a better way to communicate messages from Roslyn to developer? Ideally, i'd like to show a modal message box to them. Possibly, is there a way to cancel refactoring and give cancelation reason from inside its own code?

Answer (score 0):

Your refactoring is going to be running from within Visual Studio, therefore you can use any of the APIs that a Visual Studio extension can use.  I would take a look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples) github repository for some examples about what APIs are available.